# jQuery Autocomplete function doesnt work in new browsers

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to incorporate jQuery autocomplete. It works fine with Firefox 3.6.. However it doesnt work in in Chrome 10, Firefox 9, IE 7-9, Opera, Safari 5. Basically all the new browsers.
Using debugging tools, the there is a server side response in the format ["Router","Microsoft Outlook 2007",] across all browsers. However the drop down does not appear,except one browser.

**Header Files**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
   $(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $("#textbox")
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                                    var url=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/test/generateList";
                            $.getJSON(url, {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
            });
```

**Element**

Comment: It could be that you have duplicate functions in your includes, not sure but does jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js contain some of the functions in jquery.ui.core.js for example?  Try taking out some of the library references.

Comment: tried playing with all the files, but that didnt help

Comment: Whenever I use autocomplete, I only have script tags for jQuery and jQuery UI, I've never explicitly included scripts like that and Autocomplete always works for me. Could you possibly post a link to the page? Also, I wouldn't call Chrome 10 recent :P

Comment: Sorry I can't post the link as project is internal. Sorry I didn't get your suggestion. I am new to jQuery. Sorry just not sure what version of chrome is currently in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the response.. ["Router","Microsoft Outlook 2007",]. Please note the extra comma(,) at the end. If response is ["Router","Microsoft Outlook 2007"].. It works.

Answer (score 0):

any JS errors you can see from the browser developer tools.(firebugs for firefox and so on)

Comment: Yes I did use the firebug and developer tools on each browser. That's how I concluded that server side response was successful